# Prove that the Cantor set is homeomorphic to $(X,\mathscr T)$.

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof, cantor-set

For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $X_n=\{0,2\}$ and let $\mathscr T_n $ be the discrete topology on $X_n$. Let $X=\prod_{n=1}^\infty X_n,$ and $\mathscr T$ be the product topology on $X$. Prove that the Cantor set is homeomorphic to $(X,\mathscr T)$.

Proof. Let $C$ be the Cantor set, Let $(C,\mathscr U_C)$ be the subspace topological space of usual topology on $\mathbb R$. Let the map $\psi:(C,\mathscr U_A)\to (X,\mathscr T)$ be defined as $\psi(x)=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,....),$ where $x\in C$  and $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x_i}{3^i},x_i=0$or $2$. $\psi$ is well defined if we take the ternary expansion of $1/3,1/9$,...etc with $0$ and $2$ s. We can easily prove that $\psi$ is injective.

How do I prove that $\psi$ is surjective? What is the guarentee that, If $y\in X$, $\exists x\in C$:$f(x)=y$?

For continuity of $\psi$, Let $\mathscr B$ be the basis of the product topology on $X$. It is enough to show that $\psi^{-1}(B)\in \mathscr U_C$ for every $B\in \mathscr B$. Let $B \in \mathscr B$, $B=\prod_{i=1}^n B_i$, $B_i \in \mathscr T_i$, $B_i=X_i$ for all but finitely many $i$. I want to prove $\exists$ some open interval ($I$(say) in $\mathbb R$) such that $\psi^{-1}(B)=C\cap I$. How do I prove the existence of $I$?

For completing the proof of homeomorphism, I need to prove that $\psi $ is open. Let $U\in \mathscr U_C$, then $U=C\cap J$ for some interval $J$ in $\mathbb R$. then $\psi(U)=\psi(C\cap J)=\psi(C)\cap\psi(J)=X\cap \psi(J).$ How do I complete the proof. Please help me.

Comment: For surjectivity, note that both sides of $\psi$ are sequences of $0$s and $2$s.

Comment: What if there exists a  sequence $(a_1,a_2,...,)$, where $a_i=0$ or $2$. but $\sum \frac{a_i}{3^i}$ is not in cantor set. Is it possible? If not why?

Comment: If you look at the form of the sum you will see that it corresponds to $.a_1a_2...$ which is a base three fraction. Your sum $is$ a "decimal" expansion of each element of the Cantor set.

Comment: @Unknownx: A simple way to go is to observe, from the construction of the Cantor set, that it contains any *finite* sum $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i/3^i$ where $a_i \in \{0,2\}$; indeed, such a value is an endpoint of one of the removed open intervals.  Now note that any such *infinite* sum is by definition a limit of finite sums, and the Cantor set is closed...

Comment: For the last part: (1) the complement of an open set is compact (2) continuous functions take compact sets to compact sets.  Indeed, this proves more generally that any continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces is automatically a homeomorphism.

Comment: I am learning from patty Foundations of Topology, I have reached at connectedness only. compactness comes after connectedness.

Comment: Let $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...)\in B=B_1\times B_2 \times B_3...\times B_N \times B_{N+1}...$. So, $\exists$ $N\in \mathbb N$: $B_n=X_n, \forall n\ge N$. Let $x\in C$: $x=\sum \frac{a_i}{3^i}$
Geometrically I could prove that $ \psi((x-\frac{1}{3^{N+2},x+\frac{1}{3^{N+2})\subset B $
How do I prove abstractly?